# ERROR::ASSIMP:: Expected different index count in <p> element

Tags: c++, cmake, segmentation-fault, assimp

I developed a project on windows with visual studio 17 and it worked fine for me. Now I'm compiling it with cmake on a linux virtual machine (in virtualbox) and everything seems to be ok but when I run my program Assimp doesn't work.

When I create an importer to load an animation it prints an error:

```
ERROR::ASSIMP:: Expected different index count in <p> element.
```

but what drives me crazy is that it doesn't cause a crash in the program but it keeps going after printing this, it gets the scene like nothing happened, an assert is passed but when i take the animations i get a segmentation fault.

Here the code:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(animationPath, aiProcess_Triangulate);
assert(scene && scene->mRootNode);
auto animation = scene->mAnimations[0];
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

To reproduce it:
Virtualbox with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS os.

the repo can be cloned from [here](https://github.com/francescoschembri/TesiReskinner)

You need Conan installed.
When Conan is installed, just clone the repo and run the script called installer.sh
it just installs some dependencies like xorg-dev, build-essential etc with apt-get install and some libraries with conan and configures the makefile with cmake and build it. Then, go to the build dir and run the program called Reskinner.

Comment: This question needs a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added infos to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the collada-implementation. The number of indices does not fit to the kind of primitive. I am not sure if this is caused by a wrong expectation from our collada parser or from an invalid model.

You can find the issue-report here: [Problem with wrong indices](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/4551)